# SSH : do we need to regenerate the public/private key whenever the IP addresses of server or client changes?

Tags: ssh

Do we need to regenerate the public/private keys whenever the IP addresses of the server or client changes?

How do we enable the logging of the sshd so that i could see the conversation between the server and the client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to regenerate keys when IP addresses change.  You may need to accept the certificate again, but you would need to accept a new certificate anyway.

If a different host connects to an IP from which you had previously connected, you will get a warning that a different key is associated with the IP address.  The message should include instructions for removing the old key.  Regenerating the key will cause this to happen if the host returns to an old IP address.

Your security log (usually auth.log or authlog) should log all incoming ssh sessions.  Logging traffic flowing over ssh connections would require breaking the security of ssh which is intended to provide security against such traffic inspection.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you don't need to regenerate the keys.
2. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Look for `LogLevel`. The default is info. Here are your choices (lowest to highest):

QUIET, FATAL, ERROR, INFO, VERBOSE, DEBUG, DEBUG1, DEBUG2 and DEBUG3

Then restart sshd service. Remember that DEBUG values violate user privacy, as stated on the [sshd_config manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config).

You can see the logs either by running `journalctl _COMM=sshd` or `grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log`. `/var/log/auth.log` shows failed logins. I haven't tried journalctl yet.